# Hyperref - 'non-form' text randomly positioned

Tags: hyperref, positioning, forms

I was wondering if there was a way to put a title and bit of a blurb before it gets into a form (which otherwise works a treat!). The normal text keeps getting interjected into the middle randomly - I'd really appreciate any help on this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array} % Allows matrix-type array for the table
\usepackage{hyperref} % Allows a fillable pdf to be output
\usepackage{todonotes}

\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % Ascribes 'p' the column type of horizontally centred
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} % Ascribes 'm' the column type of vertically and horizontally centred

\begin{document}
\begin{center}  

\Large \textbf{A title}
Some text I'd really love to be ABOVE where the form starts. Basically a bit of a blurb about what the form is\\
\todo{Oh text... Why you no worky? Go to your home} % Using to do notes 
\end{center}    

\begin{Form}
\begin{center}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|M{2cm}|M{5cm}|M{1.75cm}|M{1.5cm}|M{2cm}|}
        \hline
\textbf{Catalogue No.} & \textbf{Product Name} & \textbf{Quantity} & \textbf{Pack Size} & \textbf{Order No.} \\ 
\hline
\TextField[name = 1, width = 2cm]{ } & \TextField[name = 2, width = 5cm]{ } & \TextField[name = 3, width = 1.75cm]{ } & \TextField[name = 4, width = 1.5cm]{ } & \TextField[name = 5, width = 2cm]{ } \\
\hline
\TextField[name = 6, width = 2cm]{ } & \TextField[name = 7, width = 5cm]{ } & \TextField[name = 8, width = 1.75cm]{ } & \TextField[name = 9, width = 1.5cm]{ } & \TextField[name = 5, width = 2cm]{ } \\
\hline\TextField[name = 10, width = 2cm]{ } & \TextField[name = 11, width = 5cm]{ } & \TextField[name = 12, width = 1.75cm]{ } & \TextField[name = 13, width = 1.5cm]{ } & \TextField[name = 5, width = 2cm]{ } \\
\hline\TextField[name = 14, width = 2cm]{ } & \TextField[name = 15, width = 5cm]{ } & \TextField[name = 16, width = 1.75cm]{ } & \TextField[name = 17, width = 1.5cm]{ } & \TextField[name = 5, width = 2cm]{ } \\
\hline\TextField[name = 18, width = 2cm]{ } & \TextField[name = 19, width = 5cm]{ } & \TextField[name = 20, width = 1.75cm]{ } & \TextField[name = 21, width = 1.5cm]{ } & \TextField[name = 5, width = 2cm]{ } \\
\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \newline\newline
\end{table}
\end{center}
\TextField{Something to put in here:}

\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your tabular is in a table environment and so can float. If you don't want this, don't use table, or check the other options: http://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-figurehere

Comment: To make the comment above more explicit: remove the two lines `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}` from your code (and leave the `\begin{tabular}` and `\end{tabular}` lines and the actual table contents as they are now) and then the order of the elements in the output will be the same as the order in the code.

Comment: Thanks very much for the comments folks, Ulrike I found my answer with the \float package, never even considered it was the table that was the actual problem.